# "logoutOtherDevices" isn't working with Laravel Sanctum

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-8, laravel-sanctum

i want to use `Auth::logoutOtherDevices($currentPassword)` in laravel 8 to logout user from other devices after changing password. As per documentation ia have uncomment the line `\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,`. But unfortunately, it's not working. It says `Method Illuminate\Auth\RequestGuard::viaRemember does not exist.` Can anyone please help me to sort it out how can i add logout from other devices functionality with the help of `Auth::logoutOtherDevices($currentPassword)` or any manual method ?

Here is my code:

```
$rules = [
        'currentpass' => 'required',
        'newpass'     => 'required|min:6',
        'confnewpass' => 'required|same:newpass|min:6'
    ];

    $messages = [
        'currentpass.required' => 'Please enter your current password.',
        'newpass.required'     => 'Please provide a new password.',
        'newpass.min'          => 'Password must contain minimum 6 characters.',
        'confnewpass.required' => 'Please provide your new password again to confirm.',
        'confnewpass.same'     => 'Both new passwords must be same.',
        'confnewpass.min'      => 'Password must contain minimum 6 characters.'
    ];

    $this->validate($request, $rules, $messages);

    $currentPass = $request->input('currentpass');
    $newPass     = $request->input('newpass');

    try {
        $user = User::findOrFail(Auth::id());
    } catch (ModelNotFoundException $ex) {
        $response['error'] = true;
        $response['errors']['notFound'] = ['User Not Found.'];

        return response()
            ->json($response, 400, [], JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    }

    if (!Hash::check($currentPass, $user->password)) {
        return Redirect::back()
            ->withErrors(['Current Password', 'Please provide your current password properly.']);
    }

    $isChar = preg_match('/[a-zA-Z]+/', $newPass);
    $isNum  = preg_match('/\d+/', $newPass);

    if (!($isChar && $isNum)) {
        $response['error'] = 'Password must contain minimum 6 characters with at-least one letter and one number.';

        return response()
            ->json($response, 200, [], JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    }

    /** hash password */
    $hashpass = Hash::make($newPass);

    $user->password = $hashpass;

    try {
        $user->save();
    } catch (QueryException $ex) {
        return Redirect::back()
            ->withErrors(['query', $ex->getMessage()]);
    }

    Auth::logoutOtherDevices($currentPass);

    return Redirect::back()
        ->with('success', 'Your password has been successfully updated.');
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because Laravel Sanctum is using its own middleware, namely `Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful`. While `Auth::logoutOtherDevices($currentPassword)` needs `\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession` to work.

To work around this, you can extend `\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession` to works with `Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful`. Here's the steps:

1. Create a new file `AuthenticateApiSession.php` in `app/Http/Middleware` (or any other folder you like). The `AuthenticateApiSession.php` should looks like this:

   ```
   <?php

   namespace App\Http\Middleware;

   use Closure;
   use Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession;

   class AuthenticateApiSession extends AuthenticateSession
   {
       /**
        * Handle an incoming request.
        *
        * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
        * @param  \Closure  $next
        * @return mixed
        */
       public function handle($request, Closure $next)
       {
           if (! $request->hasSession() || ! $request->user()) {
               return $next($request);
           }

           // Remove or comment this code block, or you'll get error.
           /*if ($this->auth->viaRemember()) {
               $passwordHash = explode('|', $request->cookies->get($this->auth->getRecallerName()))[2] ?? null;

               if (! $passwordHash || $passwordHash != $request->user()->getAuthPassword()) {
                   $this->logout($request);
               }
           }*/

           if (! $request->session()->has('password_hash')) {
               $this->storePasswordHashInSession($request);
           }

           if ($request->session()->get('password_hash') !== $request->user()->getAuthPassword()) {
               $this->logout($request);
           }

           return tap($next($request), function () use ($request) {
               $this->storePasswordHashInSession($request);
           });
       }
   }
   ```
2. Add the newly created `App\http\Middleware\AuthenticateApiSession` class to `api` middleware group in `app/Http/Kernel.php`. Beware that it must be inserted after `EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful`.

   ```
    'api' => [
        EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\AuthenticateApiSession::class,
        'throttle:240,1',
        'auth:airlock', 
        'branch.default', 
        'bindings',
    ],
   ```

That's it, now every ajax request to guarded API endpoint from other device should returns `401` response after `Auth::logoutOtherDevices($currentPassword)` is called.
You should set your SPA (You're using sanctum, so I assume you're building an SPA) to handle invalid session in the ajax request though. Maybe redirecting the user to login page using javascript when encountering `401` ajax response.

Comment: Update: I had to override the auth function and specify the web guard aswell, in case someone was wondering. On my SPA using cookies it throws me the function logoutCurrentDevice doesn't exist and on POSTMAN it works just fine, thats why.